# Converting adoc to markdown while preserving latex style math equations

Tags: python, regex, latex, pandoc, asciidoc

I have a group of adoc documents that I'm converting to markdown. For most of them I've been able to convert them with:

```bash
asciidoc -b docbook -o temp.xml <infile>
pandoc -f docbook -t markdown_strict --atx-headers --mathjax temp.xml -o <outfile>
```

followed by some regex to clean up some broken image links and fix the headers. However, this doesn't work for the in-line math equations. In the adoc they are in the syntax: `latexmath:[$some_equation_here$]` sometimes without the dollar signs for multi-line equations.

when this gets turned into the DocBook XML it seems to be preserved and is of the format:

```xml
<inlineequation>
<alt><![CDATA[$some_equation_here$]]></alt>
<inlinemediaobject><textobject><phrase></phrase></textobject></inlinemediaobject>
</inlineequation>
```

but when pandoc converts it back to markdown it ignores these blocks of xml. How can i keep it in a markdown readable equation ($some_equation_here$) format during the pandoc conversion? The `mathjax` extension doesn't seem to be helping with this operation.

I tried to use a seperate python regex that would use `re.sub(r'latexmath:\[\$?(.*?)\$?\]', r'$\g<1>$', file_contents` to keep the $ but it results in some double escaped text that then has to go be fixed manually as well as not fully working sometimes giving some extra `/sup` tags. Trying to do something similar with the XML file resulted in similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the pandoc code it seems that the DocBook reader expects the formula to be in an `<mathphrase>` element below `<inlineequation>`. Thus, replacing the `<alt>` tags with `<mathphrase>` is enough to get the equation to be picked up by pandoc. This yields invalid DocBook XML in general, as the `<inlineequation>` should contain *either* a `<mathphrase>` *or* `<inlinemediaobjects>`, but that doesn't matter for pandoc.

```bash
cat << EOF | pandoc --from=docbook --to markdown --lua-filter=unwrap-math.lua
<para>
  <inlineequation>
    <mathphrase><![CDATA[$some_equation_here$]]></mathphrase>
    <inlinemediaobject><textobject><phrase></phrase></textobject></inlinemediaobject>
  </inlineequation>
</para>
EOF
$some_equation_here$
```

Note that pandoc inserts the dollars itself, so those should be removed as well. The above command uses a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to remove the dollars; `unwrap-math.lua` contains

```lua
function Math (mth)
  mth.text = mth.text:gsub('^%$', ''):gsub('%$$', '')
  return mth
end
```